# Extract list of dictionaries from dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Dataframe is like that

[image: dataframe]

and I want to extract that row values into same dataframe.

```
df["row"][0] values like
```

> [{'acceleration': 0,
> 'distance': 0.917,
> 'energy_cost': 4.644,
> 'estimated_energy': 76.323,
> 'half': 1,
> 'metabolic_power': 17.043,
> 'pos_x': -27.14,
> 'pos_y': 50.03,
> 'speed': 3.67,
> 'video_second': 5.0},
> {'acceleration': 0,
> 'distance': 0.848,
> 'energy_cost': 4.647,
> 'estimated_energy': 70.546,
> 'half': 1,
> 'metabolic_power': 15.753,
> 'pos_x': -27.988,
> 'pos_y': 50.022,
> 'speed': 3.39,
> 'video_second': 5.25},
> {'acceleration': 0,
> 'distance': 0.848,
> 'energy_cost': 3.978,
> 'estimated_energy': 60.39,
> 'half': 1,
> 'metabolic_power': 13.485,
> 'pos_x': -28.835,
> 'pos_y': 50.015,
> 'speed': 3.39,
> 'video_second': 5.5},
> {'acceleration': 0,
> 'distance': 0.848,
> 'energy_cost': 4.647,
> 'estimated_energy': 70.546,
> 'half': 1,
> 'metabolic_power': 15.753,
> 'pos_x': -29.682,
> 'pos_y': 50.008,
> 'speed': 3.39,
> 'video_second': 5.75},
> {'acceleration': 0,
> 'distance': 0.848,
> 'energy_cost': 4.647,
> 'estimated_energy': 70.546,
> 'half': 1,
> 'metabolic_power': 15.753,
> 'pos_x': -30.53,
> 'pos_y': 50.0,
> 'speed': 3.39,
> 'video_second': 6.0},
> {'acceleration': 0.445,
> 'distance': 0.959,
> 'energy_cost': 4.647,
> 'estimated_energy': 79.805,
> 'half': 1,
> 'metabolic_power': 17.82,
> 'pos_x': -31.345,
> 'pos_y': 50.505,
> 'speed': 3.835,
> 'video_second': 6.25},
> {'acceleration': 0,
> 'distance': 0.959,
> 'energy_cost': 5.91,
> 'estimated_energy': 101.505,
> 'half': 1,
> 'metabolic_power': 22.666,
> 'pos_x': -32.16,
> 'pos_y': 51.01,
> 'speed': 3.835,
> 'video_second': 6.5},
> {'acceleration': 0.0,
> 'distance': 0.959,
> 'energy_cost': 4.647,
> 'estimated_energy': 79.805,
> 'half': 1,
> 'metabolic_power': 17.82,
> 'pos_x': -32.975,
> 'pos_y': 51.515,
> 'speed': 3.835,
> 'video_second': 6.75},
> {'acceleration': 0,
> 'distance': 0.959,
> 'energy_cost': 4.644,
> 'estimated_energy': 79.761,
> 'half': 1,
> 'metabolic_power': 17.81,
> 'pos_x': -33.79,
> 'pos_y': 52.02,
> 'speed': 3.835,
> 'video_second': 7}]

Desired dataframe is like id, number, acc, distance, ... and sorted with video second.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

# if not converted already, apply ast.literal_eval
df["row"] = df["row"].apply(literal_eval)

df = df.explode("row")
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("row").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1).sort_values(
    "video_second"
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    id  number  acceleration  distance  energy_cost  estimated_energy  half  metabolic_power   pos_x   pos_y  speed  video_second
0  340       6         0.000     0.917        4.644            76.323   1.0           17.043 -27.140  50.030  3.670          5.00
0  340       6         0.000     0.848        4.647            70.546   1.0           15.753 -27.988  50.022  3.390          5.25
0  340       6         0.000     0.848        3.978            60.390   1.0           13.485 -28.835  50.015  3.390          5.50
0  340       6         0.000     0.848        4.647            70.546   1.0           15.753 -29.682  50.008  3.390          5.75
0  340       6         0.000     0.848        4.647            70.546   1.0           15.753 -30.530  50.000  3.390          6.00
0  340       6         0.445     0.959        4.647            79.805   1.0           17.820 -31.345  50.505  3.835          6.25
0  340       6         0.000     0.959        5.910           101.505   1.0           22.666 -32.160  51.010  3.835          6.50
0  340       6         0.000     0.959        4.647            79.805   1.0           17.820 -32.975  51.515  3.835          6.75
0  340       6         0.000     0.959        4.644            79.761   1.0           17.810 -33.790  52.020  3.835          7.00
```

Comment: It gives this error "ValueError: malformed node or string:"

Comment: When I remove df["row"] = df["row"].apply(literal_eval) it works!

Comment: @AltanHalıgür If values in `df["row"]` are already of `list` type, don't apply `literal_eval`